# Matching comma after certain phrase

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm using Atom's regex search and replace feature and not JavaScript code.

I thought this JavaScript-compatible regex would work (I want to match the commas that have `Or rather` behind it):

```
(?!\b(Or rather)\b),
```

- `?!`  =  Negative lookahead
- `\b`  =  word boundary
- `(...)`  =  search the words as a whole not character by character
- `\b`  =  word boundary
- `,`  =  the actual character.

However, if I remove characters from "Or rather" the regex still matches. I'm confused.

https://regexr.com/4keju

Comment: Are you trying to _match_ `Or rather` before a comma, or anything _other_ than `Or rather` before a comma?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm trying to match the comma. Any comma that has `Or rather` behind it.

Comment: `(?:or rather)(,)`

Comment: `I want to match the commas that have Or rather behind it` but in pattern you're using negative lookbehind

Comment: @alexchenco you can use lookbehind in atom [`read this thread`](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-search-regex-negative-lookbehind/57297/4)

Comment: @CodeManiac There is no need using an unanchored lookbehind in this scenario. There won't be any overlapping matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?!\b(Or rather)\b),` pattern is equal to `,` as the negative lookahead always returns true since `,` is not equal to `O`.

To remove commas after `Or rather` in *Atom*, use

**Find What**: `\b(Or rather),`
**Replace With**: `$1`

Make sure you select the `.*` option to enable regular expressions (and the `Aa` is for case sensitivity swapping).

`\b(Or rather),` matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(Or rather)` - Capturing group 1 that matches and saves the `Or rather` text in a memory buffer that can be accessed using `$1` in the replacement pattern
- `,`  - a comma.

JS regex demo:

```js
var s = "Or rather, an image.\nor rather, an image.\nor rather, friends.\nor rather, an image---\nOr rather, another time they.";
console.log(s.replace(/\b(Or rather),/g, '$1'));
// Case insensitive:
console.log(s.replace(/\b(Or rather),/gi, '$1'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to match the `,` without relying on `$1`? I'm using Atom's regex search and replace feature and not JavaScript code.

Comment: @alexchenco Well, I think the only way in Atom is what I showed in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant to use positive lookbehind instead of negative lookbehind

```
(?<=\b(Or rather)\b),
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/bd6OK9/1/)

You can activate `lookbehind` in atom using flags, [`Read this thread`](https://discuss.atom.io/t/atom-search-regex-negative-lookbehind/57297/4)

Answer (score 0):

To Match any comma after "Or rather" you can simply use
(or rather)(,) and access the second group using match[2]

Or an alternative would be to use or rather as a non capturing group
(?:or rather)(,) so the first group would be commas after "Or rather"